# How can i style my django filter with bootstrap or CSS

Tags: css, django, django-filter

i'm new to django here and still learning. So, i created a filter using django-filter and i didn't know how to style it (bootstrap or CSS) because i really don't like the default styling. Can anyone help me with it? i already googled it but didn't find anything useful.

filters.py 
`

```
class CompLink_Filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = DateFilter(field_name="date_added", label='Date ajout' ,lookup_expr='gte')
    company_name = CharFilter(field_name='company_name', label='Nom Entreprise' ,lookup_expr='icontains')
    sector = CharFilter(field_name='sector',label='Secteur' , lookup_expr='icontains')
    size = CharFilter(field_name='size', label='Taille' ,lookup_expr='icontains')
    phone = CharFilter(field_name='phone', label='Téléphone' ,lookup_expr='icontains')
    employees_on_linkedin = CharFilter(field_name='employees_on_linkedin', label='Employés sur Linkedin :' ,lookup_expr='icontains')
    type = CharFilter(field_name='type', label='Type' ,lookup_expr='icontains')
    founded_in = CharFilter(field_name='founded_in', label='Fondée En' ,lookup_expr='icontains')
    specializations = CharFilter(field_name='specializations', label='Spécialisations' ,lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Comapny_Profile
        fields= '__all__'
        exclude= ['company_link','website','head_office','address']`
```

displaying the filter in my template:

```
<form class="" action="" method="get">

  {% for field in myFilter.form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Recherche</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery or javascript to manipulate the DOM. When the tags are created you can style it. For example.

```
$("input").addClass("form-group");
```